# custom url rewrite for wordpress

Tags: php, customization, htaccess, rewrite-rules

Can we rewrite bellow url in wordpress site?

I want to hit the following wordpress url:

```
 test/test-post/index.shtml
```

with this url "custom" is my folder at root path and custom.php file

```
custom/custom.php?cat=1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been struggling with this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^test/test-post/index.shtml$ custom/custom.php?cat=1 [L,R]
```

The `[L]` flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set.

Use of the `[R]` flag causes an HTTP redirect to be issued to the browser.

Comment: Thanks, but none of the above helps. Redirection not working.currently my htaccess is  # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dexter-armystudy/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /dexter-armystudy/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: i have trying in my local server. So, is it working on local server or not?

Comment: Retested and work on my local and remote server. `RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^test/test-post/index.shtml$ custom/custom.php?cat=1 [L,R]
# BEGIN WordPress 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On 
 RewriteBase /dexter-armystudy/ 
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
 RewriteRule . /dexter-armystudy/index.php [L] 
 </IfModule> 
# END WordPress `. Navigate to `example.com/test/test-post/index.shtml` and it will redirect you to the `example.com/custom/custom.php?cat=1`

Comment: If "custom is my folder at root path" then you will need a slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` _substitution_, otherwise, it is going to be redirected relative to the `RewriteBase`, which appears to be set to `/dexter-armystudy/`. However, is an external redirect required here? The question states "rewrite". If an _internal rewrite_ is required then you'll also need to remove the `R` flag.